# Branch had an error being deployed - Github

Tags: github, deployment, github-api

I am seeing this strange error from a couple of days, where in when a PR is opened in Github, the necessary checks are passed, but I see an error stating "This " though the deployment is successful (the changes are reflected in the deployment) and merging is also successful. I know this is not breaking anything in the flow, but I want to resolved this error which says "1 abandoned deployment". I can confirm I have not made any code changes or anything.

[image]

Comment: I am staring at this right now.  Have you gained any additional context here?  Is there a way to get more details on the specific error?

Comment: A rebase at least allowed me to get past the error.  Still no idea what caused it or where to investigate the source.